# Send webbrowser data to another webbrowser. (python prefereable)

Tags: python, web, browser, tunneling, http-tunneling

I have an unlimited internet connection in my house and a limited internet connection in the school.

I want to make a web browser (or something like that) that navigate from my house, get the data (including the streamings), and resends it to my browser in the school.

In Python, using WebKit, a web browser can be created easily and navigate youtube and other pages, I want to recreate that navigation in the other web browser (the one connected in my school).

> School browser ⟶ send request to program or another Web browser ⟶ get page data (including streaming) ⟶ tunneling ⟶ sent to school browser.

It’s something like to do a remote web browser.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to make a home private proxy server.

There are plenty of guides on how to do this but here's one I found by quickly looking around:
https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/sploit-make-proxy-server-python-0161232/

Depending on your school's restriction method, a proxy server may not be enough to bypass their restrictions. You may also be able to overcome this by completely encrypting communications between your home network and your school system. To do this you would need to set up a home virtual private network (VPN). There are also many guides that you can use to achieve this.

Comment: yap its something like that but i dont want to send the data trough a socket (ports are blocket) but by text (whatsapp, facebook, irc, etc etc ) thanks in advantage.

Comment: @user2636742 You need to build a custom extension that connects to your proxy or VPN. There are many proxies and VPNs that work by browser extension. I suggest you check out the source code and create one that would allow you to connect to your home network and tunnel all the data through encryption.